# CSS import directives may only be used at the root of a document

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

I was wishing to use some features of boostrap4 inside page, made with bootstrap3. I got some things conflicting and I thought may be try to isolate focus of bootstrap4 with `scss`:

```
#plugged {
  @import 'bootstrap4.min.css';
}
```

Unfortunately it says

```
Error: CSS import directives may only be used at the root of a document.
        on line 2 of  plugged.scss
```

Is it possible to overcome?

---

Transcripts:

```
$ which sass
/usr/bin/sass
$ sass --version
Sass 3.4.23 (Selective Steve)
$ cat plugged.scss
#plugged {
  @import 'bootstrap4.min.css';
}                                                                                                                                                         
$ sass plugged.scss
Error: CSS import directives may only be used at the root of a document.
        on line 2 of plugged.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Comment: You need to add more context to your problem, are you using webpack? or some other package? https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import <- if you go to "Nesting" here it says its possible to nest imports inside other selectors in scss.

Comment: @JacekRatajewski I have opened `SCSS` file inside PhpStorm and it automatically converts it to map and css pair, writing this error into result

Comment: I think it's basic behaviour of PhpStorm then. Are you sure you have configured your FileWatchers correctly?

Comment: The same message appears if I run from command line